# Can I subscribe to a durable topic endpoint using wildcards in Solace using Java?

Tags: java, solace

The idea is to send messages to topic and consume them in stripes via pub/sub only (without queues) and using PERSISTENT delivery mode. For simplicity, lets say producer(s) publish messages to specific topics having the following hierarchy: `bus/<componentId/<transactionId>`.

Consumers want to receive topic "stripes", for simplicity lets say there are 10 consumers and they want to stripe traffic among themselves by transactionId:

- `bus/*/0*`
- `bus/*/1*`
- ...
- `bus/*/9*`

When I try to subscribe to topic endpoint using wildcards, like this:

```
    DurableTopicEndpoint topicEndpoint = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createDurableTopicEndpoint("bus/*/1*");

    ConsumerFlowProperties propsFlow = new ConsumerFlowProperties();
    propsFlow.setEndpoint(topicEndpoint);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topic Endpoint name "bus/*/1*" contains illegal character [*]
    at com.solacesystems.common.util.DestinationUtil.isValidEndpointName(DestinationUtil.java:234)
    at com.solacesystems.common.util.DestinationUtil.isValidTopicEndpointPhysicalName(DestinationUtil.java:209)
    at com.solacesystems.common.util.DestinationUtil.isValidDTEPhysicalName(DestinationUtil.java:213)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.SessionModeSupport.createFlow(SessionModeSupport.java:247)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.SessionModeSupport.createFlow(SessionModeSupport.java:170)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPBasicSession.createFlow(JCSMPBasicSession.java:953)
```

In the light of this [article](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-Messaging-APIs/Adding-Topic-Subscriptio.htm)'s section "Adding Subscriptions to Topic Endpoints" - is it at all possible with Solace Java API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. You are trying to create an `TopicEndpoint` named `bus/*/1*`. Note that this is the name of the `TopicEndpoint` and not the topic that it is subscribing to.  `*` is not a valid character for the name of a `TopicEndpoint`.
2. `TopicEndpoints` are only allowed to have one subscription. This means that you can only subscribe to `bus/*/0*`. If you want to subscribe to `bus/*/0*` all the way to `bus/*/9*` you will need to make use of a `Queue` instead of a `TopicEndpoint`.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. Yet, it looks like I have to create durable topic endpoint administratively first (from CLI or SolAdmin management), and then I can subscribe this topic endpoint to a topic stripe using *.

This is very much like using Queues and Topic to Queue mapping, i.e. create a queue administratively and subscribe it to topic stripe using *. The only difference is that queue would probably allow multiple topic stripes. Are there other differences?

Comment: You can create the endpoint programmatically using `JCSMPSession.provision()` and then apply subscription(s) to it.

Comment: Queues are significantly more flexible than topic endpoints and are the recommended approach for most applications.
The use of topic endpoints should be restricted to JMS applications.

Please refer to the documentation for a full listing of features of both queues and topic-endpoints.
https://docs.solace.com/Features/Endpoints.htm